# Partial Integration problem

Tags: integration

I came across the following equality
$$\int_0^txf(x)dx=t-\int_0^t(t-x)f(x)dx,$$
which is supposedly true because of integration by parts but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$ \int_0^t(t-x)f(x) \, dx = t\int_0^t f(x)\, dx - \int_0^t xf(x)\, dx $$
So your equality is true iff 
$$ t = t \int_0^t f(x)\, dx \iff t = 0 \vee \int_0^t f(x)\, dx = 1. $$

Comment: Thank you, I do indeed have that $\int_0^tf(x)dx=1.$